# How to loop audio on a specific View Controller

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, audio

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated

{
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"Intro",
                                              CFSTR ("wav"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);
}
```

I'm a beginner with this. I'm trying to play a wav file in the background of the view controller.  I originally made a 30 second wav file, it wouldn't play, I reduced the length of the audio file to 10 seconds and it plays fine on the view controller. My question is, how to loop this audio file and/or play a longer audio file. Also, will the audio stop when I leave the view controller.

I am using xCode 4.3
I am running the app on a iPhone4 & 4s (iOS 5.1)

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple Documentation states

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html

> You can use System Sound Services to play short (30 seconds or shorter) sounds. The interface does not provide level, positioning, looping, or timing control, and does not support simultaneous playback: You can play only one sound at a time. You can use System Sound Services to provide audible alerts. On some iOS devices, alerts can include vibration.

So no loop is available when using system sounds.

You can check out this tutorial 
http://mobileorchard.com/easy-audio-playback-with-avaudioplayer/

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/audiofile.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;

if (audioPlayer == nil)
    NSLog([error description]);
else
    [audioPlayer play];

}
```

It states that if you set the numberOfLoops property to a negative number causes the audioPlayer to loop indefinitely

And dont forget to add the AVFoundation framework to your project